# problem deployind site in python any where

Tags: python, django, web-deployment, pythonanywhere

I'm trying to deploy my Django project with pythonanywher.com but I can't I'm a beginner please help I do exactly like his:

1. creating an account
2. creating API token
3. in bash scripts `pip3.6 install --user pythonanywhere`
   and then `pa_autoconfigure_django.py --python=3.6 https://github.com/<your-github-username>/my-first-blog.git`
   but I face this and I can't figure out why it doesn't work please help

```
14:30 ~ $ pip3.6 install --user pythonanywhere 
Looking in links:
/usr/share/pip-wheels Collecting pythonanywhere   Downloading
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/15/fa/812362a3910459a7ec1da428bdf44ea3c8468b92b57459c7d4a010f65ff7/pythonanywhere-0.9.4.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: docopt in
/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pythonanywhere) (0.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in
/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pythonanywhere) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in
/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pythonanywhere) (2.22.0)
Collecting schema   Downloading
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6d/ae/835f2e0d304c9533c58fe5cbcdd9124708d32e82289fcb8d6084c908ba29/schema-0.7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting tabulate   Downloading
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c4/f4/770ae9385990f5a19a91431163d262182d3203662ea2b5739d0fcfc080f1/tabulate-0.8.7-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in
/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from
python-dateutil->pythonanywhere) (1.12.0) Requirement already
satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from
requests->pythonanywhere) (2.8) Requirement already satisfied:
chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from
requests->pythonanywhere) (3.0.4) Requirement already satisfied:
certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from
requests->pythonanywhere) (2019.9.11) Requirement already satisfied:
urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in
/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests->pythonanywhere)
(1.24.3) Collecting contextlib2>=0.5.5   Downloading
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/85/60/370352f7ef6aa96c52fb001831622f50f923c1d575427d021b8ab3311236/contextlib2-0.6.0.post1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: pythonanywhere   Building
wheel for pythonanywhere (setup.py) ... done   Created wheel for
pythonanywhere: filename=pythonanywhere-0.9.4-cp36-none-any.whl
size=30356
sha256=7bd01dd5d2d87faa19a931bd08f74e050498422a92a38f9e0b3b12b4c9bd0510
Stored in directory:
/home/bookseagull13/.cache/pip/wheels/68/35/da/800f46741a95d4c66e77c7c2e145884a7ce9d2c46af401ee29
Successfully built pythonanywhere Installing collected packages:
contextlib2, schema, tabulate, pythonanywhere Successfully installed
contextlib2-0.6.0.post1 pythonanywhere-0.9.4 schema-0.7.2
tabulate-0.8.7 

14:31 ~ $ python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow
Looking in links: /usr/share/pip-wheels Collecting Pillow  
Downloading
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/aa/12/a5e5e1b9bcd6c16eb4833069e6d586dc2b8ebbd3141a369cb1bdb9e4cc04/Pillow-7.2.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
(2.2MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 2.2MB 2.6MB/s  Installing collected packages: Pillow   Found existing installation: Pillow 6.2.1
    Uninstalling Pillow-6.2.1: ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'ContainerIO.py'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

14:33 ~ $ python -m pip install Pillow 
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will
reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your
Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future
version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about
Python 2 support in pip, can be found at
https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Looking in links: /usr/share/pip-wheels Requirement already satisfied:
Pillow in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (6.2.1) 

14:34 ~ $ python3 -m pip install Pillow 
Looking in links: /usr/share/pip-wheels
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in
/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages (6.2.1) 

14:34 ~ $ pa_autoconfigure_django.py --python=3.6
https://github.com/seagull1330/my-first-blog

< Running API sanity checks >    \
    ~<:>>>>>>>>> Cloning into '/home/bookseagull13/bookseagull13.pythonanywhere.com'... Username for
'https://github.com': seagull1330 Password for
'https://seagull1330@github.com':  remote: Enumerating objects: 243,
done. remote: Counting objects: 100% (243/243), done. remote:
Compressing objects: 100% (187/187), done. remote: Total 243 (delta
52), reused 243 (delta 52), pack-reused 0 Receiving objects: 100%
(243/243), 5.89 MiB | 0 bytes/s, done. Resolving deltas: 100% (52/52),
done. Checking connectivity... done. Checking out files: 100%
(505/505), done.

< Creating virtualenv with Python3.6 >    \
    ~<:>>>>>>>>> Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3.6 Already using interpreter /usr/bin/python3.6 Using
base prefix '/usr' New python executable in
/home/bookseagull13/.virtualenvs/bookseagull13.pythonanywhere.com/bin/python3.6
Also creating executable in
/home/bookseagull13/.virtualenvs/bookseagull13.pythonanywhere.com/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel... done.
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating
/home/bookseagull13/.virtualenvs/bookseagull13.pythonanywhere.com/bin/predeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating
/home/bookseagull13/.virtualenvs/bookseagull13.pythonanywhere.com/bin/postdeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating
/home/bookseagull13/.virtualenvs/bookseagull13.pythonanywhere.com/bin/preactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating
/home/bookseagull13/.virtualenvs/bookseagull13.pythonanywhere.com/bin/postactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating
/home/bookseagull13/.virtualenvs/bookseagull13.pythonanywhere.com/bin/get_env_details

< Pip installing django (this may take a couple of minutes) >    \
    ~<:>>>>>>>>> Looking in links: /usr/share/pip-wheels Collecting django   Downloading Django-3.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (7.8 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 7.8 MB 4.5 MB/s  Collecting asgiref~=3.2.10   Downloading asgiref-3.2.10-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Collecting sqlparse>=0.2.2   Downloading
sqlparse-0.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 40 kB 513 kB/s  Collecting pytz   Downloading pytz-2020.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 510 kB 2.6 MB/s  Installing collected packages: asgiref, sqlparse, pytz, django Successfully
installed asgiref-3.2.10 django-3.1.1 pytz-2020.1 sqlparse-0.3.1

< Creating web app via API >    \
    ~<:>>>>>>>>>

< Adding static files mappings for /static/ and /media/ >    \
    ~<:>>>>>>>>>

  _________________________________________________ /                 
\ | Updating wsgi file at                             | |
/var/www/bookseagull13_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py | \                 
/   -------------------------------------------------    \
    ~<:>>>>>>>>>

< Updating settings.py >    \
    ~<:>>>>>>>>>

< Running collectstatic >    \
    ~<:>>>>>>>>>

331 static files copied to
'/home/bookseagull13/bookseagull13.pythonanywhere.com/static'.

< Running migrate database >    \
    ~<:>>>>>>>>> SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS: post.Post.Img: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because
Pillow is not installed.
        HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/ or run command "python -m pip install Pillow". post.Post.UserImg:
(fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
        HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/ or run command "python -m pip install Pillow". Traceback (most recent call
last):   File
"/home/bookseagull13/.local/bin/pa_autoconfigure_django.py", line 47,
in <module>
    main(arguments['<git-repo-url>'], arguments['--domain'], arguments['--python'], nuke=arguments.get('--nuke'))   File
"/home/bookseagull13/.local/bin/pa_autoconfigure_django.py", line 38,
in main
    project.run_migrate()   File "/home/bookseagull13/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pythonanywhere/django_project.py",
line 96, in run_migrate
    'migrate',   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 311, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd) subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command
'['/home/bookseagull13/.virtualenvs/bookseagull13.pythonanywhere.com/bin/python',
'/home/bookseagull13/bookseagull13.pythonanywhere.com/manage. py',
'migrate']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Comment: It looks like you are installing  Pillow outside the virtual environment (so it's effectively installed for different Python version). Is it in your `requirements.txt` in the repo?

Comment: thank you very much .it was exactly the probelm .